# How do I implement the TensorFrames Spark package on Data Science Experience?

Tags: python, maven, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science-experience

I've been able to import the package:

```
import pixiedust
pixiedust.installPackage("databricks:tensorframes:0")
```

But when I try a simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorframes as tfs
from pyspark.sql import Row
data = [Row(x=[float(x), float(2 * x)],
            key=str(x % 2),
            z = float(x+1)) for x in range(1, 6)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
tfs.print_schema(df)
```

I get the following error:

...

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o97.loadClass.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging
```

...

[I've looked up the issue](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging/issues/68) and it seems like there is an older `scala-logging-slf4j` artifact in the dependency tree.  **How do I remove this artifact?**  Once it's removed, I assume I can add a newer version with PixieDust:

`pixiedust.installPackage("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10/2.1.2")
pixiedust.installPackage("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging-api_2.10/2.1.2")`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140581/tensorframes-not-working-with-tensorflow-on-data-science-experience) is the follow up question.  I think it's more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charles from IBM support helped me find which jars to include:

`pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10-2.1.2.jar")
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-api_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-api_2.10-2.1.2.jar")`

This technically solves the first error, however TesnsorFrames still aren't working.  I'll post another question that is more specific.

Comment: I've posted the follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140581/tensorframes-not-working-with-tensorflow-on-data-science-experience).