# TensorFrames not working with Tensorflow on Data Science Experience

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, data-science-experience

This is a follow up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120979/how-do-i-implement-the-tensorframes-spark-package-on-data-science-experience) question.  I've imported the following jars into my notebook:

`pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10-2.1.2.jar")
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-api_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-api_2.10-2.1.2.jar")`

But when I do an extremely basic command using tensorframes, I get the following error:

```
import tensorframes as tfs
from pyspark.sql import Row
data = [Row(x=[float(x), float(2 * x)],
            key=str(x % 2),
            z = float(x+1)) for x in range(1, 6)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
tfs.print_schema(df)


.... NoClassDefFoundError: org.tensorflow.DataType ....
```

I can't update Tensorflow any more than it is, and even the latest version using python 3.5 is giving me an error.  How should I be implementing tensorframes in IBM's [Data Science Experience](https://datascience.ibm.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a jar that will get passed the above code, but I can't do any computations using TensorFrames.  I suppose I can ask another follow up question:

```
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/libtensorflow/1.1.0/libtensorflow-1.1.0.jar")
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142175/tensorframes-on-ibms-data-science-experience) is the final iteration of this question.