# TensorFrames on IBM's Data Science Experience

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, data-science-experience

This is a follow up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140581/tensorframes-not-working-with-tensorflow-on-data-science-experience/44141659#44141659) question.  I want to implement TensorFrames on IBM's Data Science Experience.  I will consider it working if I can run all of the examples on the [user guide](https://github.com/databricks/tensorframes/wiki/TensorFrames-user-guide) for TensorFrames.  I've had to import the following packages to do anything at all with TensorFrames:

```
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10-2.1.2.jar")
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-api_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-api_2.10-2.1.2.jar")
pixiedust.installPackage("http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/libtensorflow/1.1.0/libtensorflow-1.1.0.jar")
```

The error I'm currently stuck at is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: linux, architecture: x86_64
```

which leads me to believe TensorFlow wasn't properly installed.  In this case, I'm using Python 3.5 and Spark 2.1.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you get the error message during the pixidust command execution or by some other code ?

Comment: It looks like I can import the latest version now.  I'll have to see if the rest of the code in that tutorial works.

Comment: Ok, because import works for me for Scala, but for Python and I face a few ClassLoader issues in Scala.